# Can I drop the “one” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“I think immigration is becoming a national issue and ONE that will need to be addressed by all parties in the fall.”
If I drop the “ONE”,will it cause any difference of the meaning？

Comment: If you leave out the indefinite pronoun [one] in the second clause, [it] will become ungrammatical

Comment: No, you can't. Yes, it does.

Answer (score -1):

Use hyphenation and remove the "and" instead, so that it now reads

> I think immigration is becoming a national issue - one that will need to be addressed by all parties in the fall.

Comment: Gotcha.Thanks a lot，Mari-Lou A、Kris and Ameet_Khedkar.